# Sort array of objects with multiple criterias

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by an objects value. But, I need certain items in the array which reach a certain criteria to be first, and other items that reach a different criteria to be last. Otherwise, it should sort by title. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
let arr = [
    { flag: true, title: 'Orange', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: true, title: 'Apple', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: false, title: 'Peach', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: true, title: 'Plum', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: true, title: 'Mango', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: true, title: 'Banana', dateAdded: 'Some Date' },
    { flag: false, title: 'Tangerine', dateAdded: 'Some Date' }
];
```

Here are the criterias:

- If the date is within 1 week from now, that item should be first, and it should sort by date,
- If flag is set to false, that item should be last, but sort by title
- Else, sort by title

(I'll be using moment for the dates.)

So I know how to sort an array of objects, but how can I also add these 3 criterias?

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.title > b.title) return 1;
        if (a.title < b.title) return -1;

        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: With the && operator: `if (x && y) { ... } `

Comment: @rayhatfield So for the flags, it would be `if (a.flags && b.flags) return 1; if (!a.flags && !b.flags) return -1`?

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function works between 2 items, so just write the code that compares 2 items and you can define, between those 2, which one should win.

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.withinAWeek()) {
          if (b.withinAWeek()) {
            return (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : 1;
          } else {
            return -1;
          }
        }
        if (a.flag) {
          if (b.flag) {
            return (a.date < b.date) ? -1 : 1;
          } else {
            return 1;
          }
        }
        if (a.title > b.title) return 1;
        if (a.title < b.title) return -1;

        return 0;
    });
```

That is pseudocode, but that idea should work and be pretty easy to understand when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could solve this in a few, more simple steps:

1. Create three arrays from your data, first, mid, last, by running through your array and checking if:
   a. date is less than a week old, add to first
   b. flag is false, add to last
   c. neither of the above are true, add to mid
2. Sort these arrays based on the specified criteria per placement
3. return first.concat(mid.concat(last))